# Is there any text editor inside docker container?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker-compose

I have run 3 docker containers on one server.One - with nginx, two - with node apps.I can enter inside nginx container using exec command, but I want to look through the hosts file in etc. Is there any ability to do this?

**Update**
There is only cat util. You can call it as `cat your_filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you docker is a linux emulation, you can use nano.

```
$ nano file.txt
```

If you only want to read the file, but not edit it, you can do this:

```
$ less file.txt
```

Comment: tell me what OS are you emulating

Comment: if is a linux OS, you can do this to get more information about the OS: $ uname -a

Comment: Linux 53fa9213f549 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: you can do $ apt-get install nano

Comment: i edit the answer, try with the second command, this should work. If it does, accept teh answer please. Anyway, you can install some editor too, for example, $ sudo apt-get install nano

Comment: apt-get is stripped:
```
bash-4.3# uname -a
Linux 07d7efffda8b 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 Linux
bash-4.3# apt-get
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

Comment: this is incorrect. it depends on the base linux image

Answer (score 4):

The node images do not have these utilities, in order to keep them lightweight for production environments.

Once you've gotten into the container (with `docker exec -it (containerName) bash`) you can install `nano` using `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install nano`.